# How to search multiple items in JSON array in Postgres 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql-9.3

I have scenario where i need to search multiple values in a JSON array. Below is my schema.

```
   ID            DATA
   1           {"bookIds" : [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]} 
   2           {"bookIds" : [1,2], "storeIds": [1,3]}
   3           {"bookIds" : [11,12,10,9], "storeIds": [4,3]}
```

I want all the rows with value 1,2. Below is query i am using (This is query is written by one of fellow stackoverflow user Mr. klin credit to him).

```
  select t.*
  from JSONTest t, json_array_elements(data->'bookIds') books
  where books::text::int in (1, 2);
```

However output I am duplicate rows in output, below is my output.

```
     id      data
     1       {"bookIds" : [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]}
     1       {"bookIds" : [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]}
     2       {"bookIds" : [1,2], "storeIds": [1,3]}
     2       {"bookIds" : [1,2], "storeIds": [1,3]}
```

I want only two rows in output that is id 1,2. How can i do that? I don't want use Distinct due to other constraints,

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6457a/2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct conversion function from a JSON array to a "real" Postgres array. `(data ->'bookIds')::text` returns something that is nearly a Postgres array literal: e.g. `[1,2,3,5]`. If you replace the `[]` with `{}` the value can be cast to an integer array. Once we have a proper integer array we can use the `@>` to test if it contains another array:

```
select *
from jsontest
where translate((data ->'bookIds')::text, '[]', '{}')::int[] @> array[1,2];
```

`translate((data ->'bookIds')::text, '[]', '{}')` will convert `[1,2,3,5]` to `{1,2,3,5}` which then is converted to an array using `::int[]`

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6457a/4

Comment: Thanks this gave me some way to proceed :) How costly is this operation?